# How can I achieve two way choose in decision table in Drools?

Tags: drools, kie

I am using KIE IDE 7.11.0.Final. I'm using Drools Decision Table for quite a long time. But I haven't seen any document shows how to achieve this. For example, when I have to variables, gender and age, according to these two Facts, I get a type. Old way to achieve this like this:

```
+----+--------+-----+------+
| id | gender | age | type |
+----+--------+-----+------+
| 1  |      1 |  10 | A    |
| 2  |      1 |  20 | B    |
|  3 |      2 |  10 | C    |
|  4 |      2 |  20 | D    |
+----+--------+-----+------+
```

However their is another easy way

```
+--------+-----+---+
| gender | age |   |
+--------+-----+---+
|         |  10 | 20  |
|     1  | A    | B |
|     2  | C    | D |
+--------+-----+---+
```

horizontal axis is age, and vertical axis is gender. Both variables give the type value. But I found I cannot make such decision table in Drools.

Can I do it in Drools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No unfortunately, drools doesn't support two dimensional decision tables.